# check for password protected office documents

Tags: powershell

I have a need to check through a site collection and find all password protected office documents. My organisation has decided on a policy where password protection on documents will no longer be allowed and I've been given the task of finding them. Is there a way to do this in Powershell. I suspect it has something to do with the checking of file attributes but every example I have come across relates to reading from a network drive. Can this be done in sharepoint?

Answer (score 1):

The solution below will work for encrypted files in Office 2007 and later OpenXML format. If you have Office 97-2003 or other format files you will need to add tests for these.

```
# Initialise variables
$SiteCollectionUrl = "http://yoursitecollectionurl"
$Logfile = "C:\logfile.txt"

# Create log file if it doesn't already exist
if(-not (Test-Path -path $Logfile)) {
    New-Item $Logfile -type file
}

Add-Content $LogFile "$(Get-Date)"

# Select all sites in the site collection
$SPWebs = Get-SPSite $SiteCollectionUrl | Get-SPWeb -Limit All

# Loop through the sites
foreach($Web in $SPWebs) {

    Write-Host "Subsite: $($Web.Title) at $($Web.Url)"

    # Select all non-hidden document libraries under the site
    $Libraries = $Web.Lists | Where-Object { $_.Hidden -eq $false -and $_.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary" }

    # Loop through the libraries that contain items
    foreach($Doclib in $Libraries | Where { $_.items.count -gt 0 }) {

        Write-Host "Library: $($Doclib.ParentWebUrl)/$($Doclib.Title)"

        # Loop through the library items (files)
        foreach($Item in $Doclib.items) {

            # Open the file and select first ~2kb
            $Binary = $Item.file.OpenBinary()
            $Start = [System.Text.Encoding]::Default.GetString($Binary[0000..2000])

            # Test for pattern indicating encrypted Office 2007/+ format file
            if($Start -match "E.n.c.r.y.p.t.e.d.P.a.c.k.a.g.e") {

                # Record encrypted file detection in log
                Add-Content $Logfile "-- Encrypted file: $($Doclib.ParentWebUrl)/$($Item.url)"

                # Uncomment lines below to delete file
                #Write-Host "-- Deleting encrypted file: $($Doclib.ParentWebUrl)/$($Item.url)"
                #$Item.Delete()
            }
        }
    }
}

$spweb.Dispose()
```

Comment: Thanks spartanmouse works like a gem except you would need to include provision for doc sets as it bombs out when it encounters them with this error: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

At line:11 char:44

+ $Binary = $Item.file.OpenBinary <<<< ()

+ CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (OpenBinary:String) [], RuntimeException

+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull